# Why does attempting to use the "Protected" Windows Store App Bar icon crash my app?

Tags: windows-store-apps, icons, winrt-xaml, appbar, xamlparseexception

With this XAML:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Protected" Label="Privacy Policy" >
    <AppBarButton.Flyout>
        <Flyout>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="200" Text="Photrax extracts information from images you load into it. The information it extracts includes location information (where the photos were taken, when that is available) and the date and time the photo was taken. This data is stored in a local/internal/embedded (SQLite) database. This data is not stored in the cloud but only on your local device." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="13" FontFamily="Verdana">
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock MaxWidth="200" Text="To reiterate: Your data is not shared with anyone else. It is stored only on the device from which you use Photrax." TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="13" FontFamily="Verdana">
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
        </Flyout>
    </AppBarButton.Flyout>
</AppBarButton>
```

...my app crashes with, "*An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred...Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IconElement from the text 'Protected'*"

Yet "Protected" is one of the official listed icons as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj841127.aspx).

If I change this:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Protected"
```

...to this:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Help"
```

...it works fine (but doesn't sport the preferred icon), so it's my attempt to use the "Protected" icon that's causing my headaches. Why? How to remedy?

Comment: Some craven coward and/or idiot downvoted my post again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list you linked is for Windows 8. For Windows 8.1 see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx

You're probably looking for ProtectedDocument rather than Protected.